# Invalid billing period and Frequency PayPal Merchant SDK for PHP

Tags: paypal

I am really getting confused with `BillingFrequency` , `BillingPeriod` , `TotalBillingCycles` , What i am trying to achive is set up monthly billing for 12 months.

```
  $paymentBillingPeriod =  new BillingPeriodDetailsType();
    $paymentBillingPeriod->BillingFrequency = "1"; //can not be more than a year
    $paymentBillingPeriod->BillingPeriod = "Year";
    $paymentBillingPeriod->TotalBillingCycles ="12";
    $paymentBillingPeriod->Amount = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, 18); // GET Amount from Session 
    $paymentBillingPeriod->ShippingAmount = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, "0");
    $paymentBillingPeriod->TaxAmount = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, "0");
```

This is the error response from API

- Billing period must be one of Day, Week, SemiMonth, or Year Billing
- frequency must be > 0 and be less than or equal to one year

What i am doing wrong ?

Source

```
$currencyCode = "USD";
$billingStartDate = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
$subscriberName = "Name";// Session var
$token = "" ; // 
$amount = "10.00"

$RPProfileDetails = new RecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsType();
$RPProfileDetails->SubscriberName = $subscriberName;
$RPProfileDetails->BillingStartDate = $billingStartDate;

$activationDetails = new ActivationDetailsType();

$paymentBillingPeriod = new BillingPeriodDetailsType();
$paymentBillingPeriod->BillingFrequency = '12';
$paymentBillingPeriod->BillingPeriod = 'Month';

$paymentBillingPeriod->Amount = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, $amount);
$paymentBillingPeriod->ShippingAmount = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, 0.0);
$paymentBillingPeriod->TaxAmount = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, 0.0);

$scheduleDetails = new ScheduleDetailsType();
$scheduleDetails->Description = "This is recurring payment";
$scheduleDetails->ActivationDetails = $activationDetails;

$createRPProfileRequestDetail = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType();
$createRPProfileRequestDetail->Token = $token;

$createRPProfileRequestDetail->ScheduleDetails = $scheduleDetails;
$createRPProfileRequestDetail->RecurringPaymentsProfileDetails = $RPProfileDetails;
$createRPProfileRequest = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType();
$createRPProfileRequest->CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails = $createRPProfileRequestDetail;

$createRPProfileReq = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq();
$createRPProfileReq->CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest = $createRPProfileRequest;

$paypalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(Configuration::getAcctAndConfig());
try {
/* wrap API method calls on the service object with a try catch */
$createRPProfileResponse = $paypalService->CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile($createRPProfileReq);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
include_once("Error.php");
exit;
}
```

Responce

```
Ack :   
Failure
ProfileID : 
PayPal\PayPalAPI\CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseType Object
(
    [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseDetails] => PayPal\EBLBaseComponents\CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseDetailsType Object
        (
            [ProfileID] => 
            [ProfileStatus] => 
            [TransactionID] => 
            [DCCProcessorResponse] => 
            [DCCReturnCode] => 
        )

    [Timestamp] => 2015-10-07T09:14:22Z
    [Ack] => Failure
    [CorrelationID] => 1d7177ca754
    [Errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => PayPal\EBLBaseComponents\ErrorType Object
                (
                    [ShortMessage] => Invalid billing period.
                    [LongMessage] => Billing period must be one of Day, Week, SemiMonth, or Year
                    [ErrorCode] => 11518
                    [SeverityCode] => Error
                    [ErrorParameters] => 
                )

            [1] => PayPal\EBLBaseComponents\ErrorType Object
                (
                    [ShortMessage] => Invalid billing frequency
                    [LongMessage] => Billing frequency must be > 0 and be less than or equal to one year
                    [ErrorCode] => 11516
                    [SeverityCode] => Error
                    [ErrorParameters] => 
                )

            [2] => PayPal\EBLBaseComponents\ErrorType Object
                (
                    [ShortMessage] => Invalid amount
                    [LongMessage] => Bill amount must be greater than 0
                    [ErrorCode] => 11519
                    [SeverityCode] => Error
                    [ErrorParameters] => 
                )

        )

    [Version] => 106.0
    [Build] => 000000
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you modified the `BillingFrequency` and `BillingPeriod` combination and leave all the rest parameters as below,

```
$paymentBillingPeriod =  new BillingPeriodDetailsType();
//$paymentBillingPeriod->BillingFrequency = $_REQUEST['billingFrequency'];
//$paymentBillingPeriod->BillingPeriod = $_REQUEST['billingPeriod'];
$paymentBillingPeriod->BillingFrequency = "12";
$paymentBillingPeriod->BillingPeriod = "Month";
$paymentBillingPeriod->TotalBillingCycles = $_REQUEST['totalBillingCycles'];
$paymentBillingPeriod->Amount = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, $_REQUEST['paymentAmount']);
$paymentBillingPeriod->ShippingAmount = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, $_REQUEST['paymentShippingAmount']);
$paymentBillingPeriod->TaxAmount = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, $_REQUEST['paymentTaxAmount']);
```

In your case, the explanation would be (you may find the same in the code comments right above the lines you've modified):

`BillingFrequency: "How many periods you want to charge the customer"`

`BillingPeriod: "Define your unit of period"`

`TotalBillingCycles: "Optional in this case, as the combiniation of the above 2 cannot exceed one year"`

*Be noted that the SDK sample invokes the `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` API with form data posted from `merchant-sdk-php/samples/RecurringPayments/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.html.php`, so if you'd like to customized your own payload function, please make sure all the mandatory paramerters are passed.

Refer to the API Specs [Here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/), look for all the "*(Required)*" parameters in the description, and cross-check with your codes.

Comment: Pls post your SDK API response here if there's still an issue

Comment: added source and response

Comment: @Bender, there's something missing in the request source, add this line and try run it: `$scheduleDetails->PaymentPeriod = $paymentBillingPeriod;`

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the documentation from paypal;

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/

Your variables should be looking like;

```
$paymentBillingPeriod->BillingFrequency = "12"; //can not be more than a year
$paymentBillingPeriod->BillingPeriod = "Month";
```

This is because the period of payment is monthly and the frequency is 12, which rounds to 1 year.

As per the documentation quote;

`The combination of billing frequency and billing period must be less than or equal to one year. For example, if the billing cycle is Month, the maximum value for billing frequency is 12. Similarly, if the billing cycle is Week, the maximum value for billing frequency is 52.`

**Edit**
Doing it this way means you can omit the `TOTALBILLINGCYCLES` value, which cleans up the code as you have one less line to contend with.

Comment: Changed variables, still same issue